# cURL via PHP returns incomplete page content

Tags: javascript, php, html, curl

I'm trying to scrape data from (train locations in real time) http://italoinviaggio.italotreno.it/SiteCore/IT/italo/Pagine/default.aspx
via php

When visiting the page directly with a browser the results are as follows (excerpt)

```
<option value="6776">35915</option>
<option value="9968">9968</option>
<option value="6777">35918</option>
<option value="6965">35922</option>
<option value="9973">9973</option>
```

When using either cURL or file_get_contents("http://...") the returned results are as follows (excerpt)

```
<option value="6776"></option>
<option value="9968"></option>
<option value="6777"></option>
<option value="6965"></option>
<option value="9973"></option>
```

Please note the following

- **Chrome Dev tools show no XHRs**
- **The page loaded in a browser works correctly even with JS disabled**
- **Chrome Dev tools show no Flash or any other "extra" components being downloaded outside of JS HTML and CSS**

Can somebody please explain to me how it's possible?

Is it some magical aspx feature?

Comment: Do they have an official api you can use instead of scraping?

Comment: Unfortunately they don't

Comment: Try setting a user agent then in curl

Comment: If your webscraping was detected, it's quite plausible to receive only partial or dummy data.

Comment: Setting a useragent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36" doens't help

Comment: I have tried both methods and work for me. Maybe you have been blacklisted in some way. You should try from a different IP (other network, VPN or from a server) to test what @mario has said.

Comment: Damn I think you guys are right... I've been blacklisted thanks for the help

Comment: Fran could you please post your code? Have you added anything else besides a user agent?